# Extremely challenging differentiable function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

If f is a differentiable function with $f(8) = 1$ and $f'(8) = 0$, find 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left({\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}f(x^3)^2}\right)
\end{equation}

for $x=2$.

I really really really would appreciate it if someone can help me solve this... I have never been so stressed out with a math question before..

Comment: You never define $y$.

Comment: Where would you start? $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{(x^2+x^3)f(x^3)}(f(x^3)^2$ is the derivative of what? A product? A square root? A power?

Comment: @SteveKass no, can you explain to me what that is? I'm only in first year pre-calculus course and this feels like a more complicated question than it should be...

Comment: (Sorry - I first thought you had $f(x^3)^2$ in the exponent and made a comment about that, but deleted it when I saw what you had.)

Comment: You just need to treat $\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}$ and $f(x^3)^2$ as two factors and use product rule and chain rule. Then you plug in $x=2$ and use the given condition. Since differentiate $f(x^3)^2$ will result in a factor of $f^{'}(x^3)$ and $f^{'}(2^3)=0$ by assumption, actually you only need to differentiate the first factor. If my calculation is correct, the result should be $\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: OHHHHH OK. Thanks so much! @JohnZHANG

Answer (score 0):

$$ \mbox{Let}\ g(x)={\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}f(x^3)^2} $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[g(x)\right]=\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x^3)^2\right]+ f(x^3)^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}\right]
$$
$$ = 2f(x^3)\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x^3)\right]+ \frac{f(x^3)^2}{2\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}} \frac{d}{dx}\left[(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)\right] $$
$$ = 2f(x^3)\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x^3)\right]+ \frac{f(x^3)^2}{2\sqrt{(x^2+x+3)f(x^3)}} \left((x^2+x+3)\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x^3)\right]+f(x^3)(2x+1)\right)$$
So now
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[g(2)\right]= 2f(8)\sqrt{(4+2+3)f(8)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(8)\right]+ \frac{f(8)^2}{2\sqrt{(4+2+3)f(8)}} \left((4+2+3)\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(8)\right]+f(8)(4+1)\right) $$
$$ = 2\sqrt{9}(0)+ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{9}} \left(9(0)+5\right) = \frac{5}{6} $$